# 3 Dimensional Games in Python Modules

Tags: python, module, pygame

I am soon going to be helping my friend create a 3D game with Python.  Will I be able to use Tkinter for this (Which I doubt because the module only excepts .gif images) and add a Z axsis?  Or will I have to use an extra module like PGReloaded, PyGame, etc.  If so could someone give me a good place to learn the module.  By the way the name of the game will be The Search.

Comment: Yeah there is no way you could use Tk for 3D games !

Comment: I said that I doubted it and I am only 11.

Comment: its all good im only 14 do some google searches and you will find something suitable

Comment: Have a look into Panda3D: https://www.panda3d.org
Also reconsider the choice of programming language for a 3D game. There are many good enginges available for free, but they might require C++ or the like.

Answer (score 2):

I have done a bit of research in this department, although not much because python is not the ideal language for creating a 3D game in.
So here are a few pointers that I discovered.

1. **Tkinter is not a gaming engine** Although Tkinter is very easy to use and is great, it is NOT a game engine and I highly recommend you don't use it as such. Tkinter is more for developing applications and utilities. Not games.
2. **PyGame is not enough of a base to make a 3D game** PyGame is a great groundwork for game mechanics and I highly recommend that you use it for that. However, it really only supports 2D graphics, so you probably would not be able to make a good 3D game using only that.
3. **Look for functionality and support** I'm not sure there is a final, perfect, 3D game engine. Some may be good at one thing while bad at others. So look for integration with your program along with support with what you want to do. The best two that I've found, Although there may be betters out there, are Blender3D (full python support, great for modeling) and OGRE 3D (there is a full python wrapper that works great with pyGame). You may want to look [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGames) for some useful resources to get you started.

Good luck with your game, I anticipate playing "The Search" already!

Comment: Thank you for all the help!  I am glad that one person is looking forward to the game!  SPOILER ALERT: I hope you like playing a slender-like game.

Answer (score 0):

No, Tkinter is not enough for making 3D games.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this website for more details:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGames